# PreparedStatement for closable recordset and connection

Tags: java, jdbc

Following approach uses more Functional approach (non OOP), each method is passed DataSource as dependency.

I've written this piece and I'm wondering if there's something that can be improved. I wish to add ResultSet to try block but not finding any option. Is there a way?

Also please review the class MySQL.

```
public static Iterator<StateEntity> findAllPrepared(DataSource dataSource, int page, int size) throws SQLException {
    List<StateEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM states LIMIT ?, ?";
    try (
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ) {
        statement.setInt(1, page);
        statement.setInt(2, size);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            list.add(new StateEntity(rs.getString("stateId"), rs.getString("stateName")));
        }
    } finally {
        if(rs != null) rs.close();
    }
    return list.iterator();
}
```

**StateEntity**

```
public class StateEntity {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public StateEntity(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**SQL Connection**

```
public class MySQL {

    public static MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

    private static Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>(){
        {
            put("authReconnect", "true");
            put("useSSL", "false");
            put("allowMultiQueries", "true");
            put("useUnicode", "true");
            put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", "true");
            put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", "false");
            put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
        }
    };

    private static Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<String, String>(){
        {
            put("host", System.getenv("HOST") != null ? System.getenv("HOST") : "localhost");
            put("schema", System.getenv("SCHEMA") != null ? System.getenv("SCHEMA") : "usa");
            put("username", System.getenv("USERNAME") != null ? System.getenv("USERNAME") : "root");
            put("password", System.getenv("PASSWORD") != null ? System.getenv("PASSWORD") : "mypass");
        }
    };

    static {
        String query = parameters.entrySet().stream()
                .map(p -> p.getKey() + "=" + p.getValue())
                .reduce((p1, p2) -> p1 + "&" + p2)
                .orElse("");

        dataSource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://" + credentials.get("host")+":3306/" + credentials.get("schema") + "?" + query);
        dataSource.setUser(credentials.get("username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(credentials.get("password"));
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
public void testGetAllPrepared() throws SQLException {
    Iterator<StateEntity> states = State.findAllPrepared(MySQL.dataSource, 0, 5);
    long count = 0;
    while (states.hasNext()) {
        count++;
        StateEntity stateEntity = states.next();
        System.out.println(stateEntity.getId());
        assertNotNull(stateEntity);
        assertNotNull(stateEntity.getId());
        assertNotNull(stateEntity.getName());
        assertEquals(2, stateEntity.getId().length());
    }
    assertEquals(5, count);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting out with your first question: no, there isn't. But you may put the result set into another nested try block. Still not super-elegant, but a bit better in my opinion:

```
try (
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
) {
    statement.setInt(1, page);
    statement.setInt(2, size);
    try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
        while(rs.next()) {
            list.add(new StateEntity(rs.getString("stateId"), rs.getString("stateName")));
        }
    }
```

Regarding the method itself: why do you return an iterator instead of the list itself? This severely limits the capabilities of the return value without any benefit. (E.g. you cannot use `size()` or `stream()` which you could do with the list.)

Regarding the MySql class now:

Are you aware that you actually create an anonymous subclass with the map construction using curly braces and an object initializer? I never found this on par with the problem solved here. Fortunately, Java 9 brought us `Map.of`, so I recommend replacing this construct with

```
private static Map<String, String> parameters = Map.of(
    "authReconnect", "true",
    ...
);
```

Regarding the `query = ...stream...reduce...orElse`: you can achive the same by simply using a joining collector:

```
String query = parameters.entrySet().stream()
    .map(p -> p.getKey() + "=" + p.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
```

The MySql class in itself is just global variables. This is "somewhat ok" as long as you don't employ advanced dependency injection possibilities like spring or a CDI container, but keep in mind that these globals are generally regarded as bad. Advice: read up on dependency injection, and see what options there are.